# limite de requisições Google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web com google maps api javascript. O limite é 25.000, contudo, está estourando nos testes que efetuei. Alguém com bons conhecimentos sobre poderia informar:

- Existe alguma time zone para o uso da Key?
- Com qual frequência o limite de requisições com uma certa chave é renovado?

Comment: Depende do que você usa, 25000 é do uso de mapas básico, algumas APIs  tem limite de 2500 chamadas por dia conforme a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage-limits-for-javascript-api-services)

Comment: Como eu disse uso somente a de javascript: Maps, autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a documentação existem dois planos:

**Clientes do plano padrão:**

São 2.500 requisições gratuitas por dia, sendo uma combinação de requisições do lado do cliente e do lado do servidor; A cada 1000 requisições adicionais é cobrado uma taxa de $ 0,50 USD. Possui um limite de 100.000 solicitações diárias.

**Clientes do Plano Premium da API do Google Maps:**

Cota diária gratuita compartilhada de 100.000 solicitações por 24 horas; Solicitações adicionais aplicadas contra a compra anual de Créditos das APIs do Google Maps.

O Google disponibiliza uma calculadora virtual para simulação de compra de créditos: [Link para Calculadora](https://credits-calculator.appspot.com/).

***O Google disponibiliza um monitor para acompanhamento do uso das API's***

Com relação a time zone: Não existe time zone específica para uso e a renovação é sempre feita a meia-noite Horário do Pacífico (PST - Pacific Standard Time UTC-8). *"Creio que são 5 horas a menos que Brasília"*

Comment: Minha dúvida era sobre time zone, vlw. Não uso web services, só a api javascript, q são 25.000.